# Setup a Mocked (Moq) class that only exposes properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to mock (using Moq) a class set a return object on a class that only exposes two properties.

In my limited Moq experience I would normally use a Setup() lamda to define the method call and then Returns() to spit back the desired output.

What I am falling down on here is the Setup(). There isn't a "method" to call as the constructor does the work, populates the two properties and then returns.

My class that I want to mock...obviously dummied down:

```
public class CarResponse
{
    public IMetaModel meta { get; set; }
    public List<ICarModel> cars { get; set; }

    public CarResponse(Common.Models.Car car)
    {
        this.cars = new List<ICarModel>();
    }
}
```

My feeble attempt at mocking:

```
private Mock<CarResponse> _carResponse = new Mock<CarResponse>(MockBehavior.Strict);
_carResponse.Setup( ????? ).Returns(new CarResponse() { meta = new MetaModelV2(), cars = foo });
```

---

To further clarify...here is the code I am trying to write a unit test for:

```
public HttpResponseMessage AddPickup()
{
     //....code removed for brevity....

    //this repository is mocked and returns the object exactly as I want it
     var car = carRepository.GetCar(carId);

   if (!errorInfo.Any()) //This check is bogus it never gets sets
   {
     RequestHelper rqh = new RequestHelper();

     response = rqh.CreateResponse(Request, HttpStatusCode.OK, new CarResponse(car));
}
```

My unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddValidPickupCorrectResponse()
{
   //arrange
   //...lots of code here left off for setting up http context etc

  //act---
  var response = controller.AddPickup();

  //assert

}
```

If I were to use a precanned object as suggested how would I "hook" it to the code under test. For example I write a unit test that uses my pre-canned object instead of a Moq but how do I get that pre-canned object to be used by the SUT?

Comment: `CarResponse` is a `PoCo` class, why would you want to mock it?

Comment: @OldFox...yes indeed it is a PoCo...how do I "pass" it from my unit test to the SUT?

Comment: How your SUT looks like? What is the problem in the example?(the example with the `CreateResponse`) Please add the UT, the scenario you are trying to verify and the class under test...

Comment: How are you expecting your `AddPickup` method to use the mocked object? It calls `new CarResponse` directly, so how would it even know you want it to do something different?

Comment: I guess that's what you're trying to ask. You'd probably need something like a CarResponse factory that could return the mocked object when under test. But I don't think we have enough detail to know if that's really what you'd want for this scenario. Where is the `car` variable coming from? What do you want your test to assert?

Comment: @CoderDennis Added car variable epoch.

Comment: So, since your car repository is mocked, why do you need to mock `CarResponse`? Couldn't you just assert that the car contained in the response matches the one produced by the mock repository? What else do you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems which can get in the way of properly unit testing the above code:

1. new-ing up the response helper
2. new-ing up the CarResponseObject

In essence, unless a class in real POCO (i.e. only data with public setters and getters), using "new" is a killer for unit testing. I.e. it is not a unit test (test the unit/method in isolation). It tests the behavior of the CarResponse ctor, as well as the working of RequestHelper.

Consider the following changes:

1. Inject the RequestHelper (so you can mock the CreateResponse method)
2. Use and inject some mapping factory of sort, which can create CarResponseObjects from Car.
3. Consider CarResponse to implement something like IResponse, so your RequestHelper, or factory, can return interfaces.

With all of the above, your test will look like (pseudo code, not complete):

```
//arrange
//....
var carInDB = new Car();
_repoMock.Setup(...).Returns(car);

var carResponse = Mock.Of<IResponse>();
_mapperMock.Setup(m=>m.CreateResponse(car).Returns(carResponse);

var responseFromHelper = new WhateverResponseIsNeeded(); //(or create a new mock IResponse - note! new mock, different than car response
_helperMock.Setup(_controller.Request, HttpStatusCode.OK, carResponse).Returns(responseFromHelper);

//act
var response = _controller.AddPickup();

//assert
response.Should().Be.SameInstanceAs(responseFromHelper)
```

Comment: So you have wisely interpreted much of my angst. I am working with a code base that has a cyclomatic complexity of 20+ in over half. I am trying to get a unit test suite in place to provide some coverage before we begin refactoring. So as it standds now alot of the "unit test" aren't isolated but that is the goal with the refactoring. To clean up the unit test and code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetupGet and SetupSet to mock properties.  However,  I don't think you can mock concrete classes.

If you are dealing with a value type you might find it easier to not bother mocking and just used a pre-canned object.

Comment: Conceptually I understand what you are saying but in my edit you'll see where I lack some knowledge to do as you suggest.